# Triangle in space

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, vectors

Using vector notation describe the triangle ( in space ) that has as vertices the origin and the endpoints of the vectors $\overrightarrow{a}$ and $\overrightarrow{b}$.

$$$$

The solution is the following: 
[image: -]

$\overrightarrow{v}=\overrightarrow{OK}=t\overrightarrow{OM}, 0 \leq t \leq 1$

$\overrightarrow{OM}=s \overrightarrow{a}+(1-s)\overrightarrow{b}, 0 \leq s \leq 1$

So, $\overrightarrow{v}=(ts)\overrightarrow{a}+t(1-s)\overrightarrow{b}=x \overrightarrow{a}+y \overrightarrow{b}$ 
where $x=ts, y=t(1-s)$ 
and therefore $x \geq 0, y \geq 0, x+y \leq 1$.

Conversely, if $\overrightarrow{v}=x\overrightarrow{a}+y\overrightarrow{b}, x \geq 0, y \geq 0, x+y \leq 1$ then we set $t=x+y$ then $0 \leq t \leq 1$, and $s=\frac{x}{t}$, so $1-s=\frac{y}{t}$, and so $0 \leq s \leq 1$ and $\overrightarrow{v}=t(s\overrightarrow{a}+(1-s)\overrightarrow{b})$ 
So, $K$ belongs to the triangle.

$$$$

Could someone explain it to me ?? Why do we have to prove both directions??

Comment: Could you write out the whole question? It's not clear what the solution is answering

Comment: The whole question is : "Using vector notation describe the triangle ( in space ) that has as vertices the origin and the endpoints of the vectors $\overrightarrow{a}$ and $\overrightarrow{b}$. "  @Omnomnomnom

Comment: Oh whoops, I misread what you wrote

Comment: Do you have any idea?? @Omnomnomnom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first bit shows that every point in the triangle (as defined geometrically) can be written as $tsa + t(1-s)b$.  We then need to show that every such vector satisfies the geometric definition.

That is, to show that $A = B$, we show that $a \in A \implies a \in B$ and then $b \in B \implies b \in A$, so that $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$, as desired.

Comment: Could you explain to me why we take these two points K and M at these positions?? I got stuck right now...

Comment: The idea is to describe the triangle between $3$ points in terms of the line connecting two points, which is easy to characterize.  If $M$ is any point on the line connecting $A$ and $B$ and $K$ is any point on the line connecting $C$ and $M$, then $K$ can be *any* point inside the triangle.

Comment: I see... Could you explain to me further also why we have to show both directions?? "To show that $A = B$, we show that $a \in A \implies a \in B$ and then $b \in B \implies b \in A$, so that $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$, as desired." What is in this case $A$ and what is $B$??

Comment: $A$ is the set of points described as $(st)a + t(1-s)b$, and $B$ is the set of points described as $xa + yb$.

Comment: OK... Thank you very much!!